# How to Write syntax in powershell for retry the Foreach loop

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am new to VMware Powercli but i was trying to write the script to vMotion the Virtual machine within in cluster host where resources are available. In my case I have multiple cluster where HA A is enabled and DRS is configured Manual and each host need to be updated with newer version of Esxi version. Hence to put the Esxi host in maintenance mode VMs need to be migrated first and once that is done then Host without VM can be placed in Maintenance Mode. So in this context I am trying to write the Script which will migrate the VMs to other host but incase of failure will this code work?

```
param(
    [String] $vcenter_fqdn,
    [String] $vcenter_username,
    [String] $vcenter_password,
    [String] $cluster_name,
    [String] $source_host
)
    
$maxTries = 3
While ($maxTries -gt 0) {
  
    Connect-VIServer $vcenter_fqdn -User $vcenter_username -Password $vcenter_password -ErrorAction stop >$null
    $clusterhosts = Get-Cluster $cluster_name | Get-VMHost | Where-Object { $_.name -notlike "$source_host" }
    $vms = Get-VMHost $source_host | Get-VM
    $vmcount = $vms.count
    if ($vmcount -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "Host Does Not found any VM"
        break
    }
    else {
        Write-Host there are $vmcount number VMs found will try to Migrate
    
        foreach ($vm in $vms) {
            $targethost = $clusterhosts | Get-Random
            Move-VM -VM $vm -Destination $targethost >$null #-ErrorAction stop
        }
        
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it won't retry, because you `break` no matter what

Comment: You might want to use a [try/catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally) for this but something needs to be changed otherwise it wil continue to fail.

Comment: iRon- what need to be changed could you please elaborate.

Comment: Even I got servers to test this script and notice that incase if VM are not able migrate due to some error then this script is keep trying infinite. Is there a way where I might try for three time and then exit as failed Migration message.

Comment: your condition `While ($maxTries -gt 0)` always holds `$true` however, it is odd that your loop is never ending since both `if` and `else` have `break` statements.